# How to center items in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried my best but unfortunately I am not able to position the Text Center 1 and 2 elements in the middle of the navbar. Hope you can help me out. Thanks.

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-bottom" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
      <p>Left</p>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-text ???">
      <a href="#"><i>Text Center 1</i></a>
      <a href="#"><i>Text Center 2</i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should't those divs have width classes on them?

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap has a predefined centered text class `text-center` that you can add to any element/div.

example: `<div class="navbar-text text-center">`

View all bootstrap alignment classes here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment

Answer (score 0):

Just give the div that you want to center the `text-align:CENTER;` property.

Sometimes it is just easier to use plain CSS instead of Bootstrap.

```css
div.center{
  text-align:CENTER;  
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-bottom" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
 <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
      <p>Left</p>
 </div>
 <div class="navbar-text center">
   <a href="#"><i>Text Center 1</i></a>
   <a href="#"><i>Text Center 2</i></a>
 </div>
 <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
   <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This duplicates something that's already available with the `text-center` class.

Answer (score 0):

Class `text-center` helps you to center `Text Center` links only when screen-size is less then 768px (but in this case social links fall down!), if screen-size is more 768px, bootstrap's class `navbar-text` has property `float: left` and your links will be left side of navbar. To prevent its behavior, you need to apply `float: none` and `display: inline-block` properties for middle navbar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-bottom" role="navigation">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
      <p>Left</p>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-text myClass">
      <a href="#"><i>Text Center 1</i></a>
      <a href="#"><i>Text Center 2</i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.myClass {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

class `text-center` in this case is used for `div.container`

[JSFiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/axsj3L3z/)